# Strike through headlines for DONE tasks in Org

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I'd really like to have my DONE task strikken through in Org-mode. Following the snippet from http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2007-03/msg00179.html (via Sacha Chua's blog):

```
(setq org-fontify-done-headline t)
(custom-set-faces
 '(org-done ((t (:foreground "PaleGreen"
                 :weight normal
                 :strike-through t))))
 '(org-headline-done
            ((((class color) (min-colors 16) (background dark))
               (:foreground "LightSalmon" :strike-through t)))))
```

This however doesn't work for me (colors are changed but no strike-through). I *think* it might be due to the solarized theme I use: https://github.com/sellout/emacs-color-theme-solarized

Unfortunately I couldn't fix it myself... If I look at `customize-face` of org-done Strike-through has value "On", but no visual effect.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I adopted the same technique and at first strike-through did not appear, not even after `org-reload`, and gave up. Eventually (don't ask why or when!) I noticed the strike-through working.

Comment: have you reloaded your .org file?

Comment: Yes, I reloaded org, colors changed but no strike-through...

Comment: Please run  `C-u C-x =` on the headline and share the result - face, properties, etc.

Comment: character: * (42, #o52, #x2a)
    preferred charset: ascii (ASCII (ISO646 IRV))
    code point: 0x2A
    syntax: _  which means: symbol
    category: .:Base, a:ASCII, l:Latin, r:Roman
    buffer code: #x2A
    file code: #x2A (encoded by coding system utf-8-unix)
    display: by this font (glyph code)
    nil:-apple-Andale_Mono-medium-normal-normal-*-13-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1 (#x0D)
    Character code properties: customize what to show
    name: IN KHA
    general-category: Po (Punctuation, Other)
    There are text properties here:
    face org-level-2
    fontified t

Comment: Sorry, for the garbled format. I got this running it on a ** DONE line as an example of what should be strikken through. Thanks for `C-u C-x =`, I didn't know about it.

Comment: your code -should- work; but `org-level-2` indicates that/why it doesn't.  the DONE should face'd with `org-done` and the headline behind it should be in `org-headline-done`.

Comment: Please try:  evaluate that code snippet in a scratch buffer (e.g. using `eval-region`), then immediately switch to your org file, and reload the file using `C-x C-v ENTER`

Comment: Yep, that is what I'm doing. The color gets changed but there is no strike through. I have Org 7.7.

Comment: tested your version using release_7.7 from org mode's git - and works for me.  have you tried to reproduce this from a clean, `emacs -Q` ?

Comment: one thing to note, just in case, for `org-headline-done` if you aren't using a dark background you won't see lightsalmon colors or a strike through. but `org-done`'s condition should always show (thus the `t`).  check help for `defface` description of SPEC if my comment isn't clear

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I had a lot of work. Using emacs -Q still doesn't give me strike through... again... changes the color but no strike through... I use Emacs 23.3 on Mac OS X, if that would help...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a light background the snippet needs to be modified, the original author likely used a dark theme.

The key line is:

```
((class color) (min-colors 16) (background dark))
```

You could replace `(background dark)` with `(background light)`, or just remove the background s-exp completely to work in both dark and light themes.

```
((class color) (min-colors 16))
```

After an eval-buffer on `init.el` it should work for your light themes. I did a quick test with solarized light and it works.